# Layout inflater inflates FrameLayout instead of my custom view

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My aim is to inflate my custom view from layout

custom view layout:

```
<net.rhyboo.com.game_test.Piece xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/piece_view">

</net.rhyboo.com.game_test.Piece>
```

class associated with this layout:

```
package net.rhyboo.com.game_test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Piece extends ImageView {

    public Piece(Context context, AttributeSet atrs) {
        super(context,atrs);
    }

    public Piece(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

But when I try to inflate with the code:

```
//get layout inflater
LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//parent view for my custom view
FrameLayout gf =(FrameLayout)fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.game_field);
//inflation attempt
Piece p=(Piece) li.inflate(R.layout.piece_view,gf);
```

I got the error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to net.rhyboo.com.game_test.Piece

Why layout inflater generates FrameLayout while type of my view is Piece which is subclass of the ImageView?

Comment: post your full xml

Comment: `Piece p=(Piece) li.inflate(R.layout.piece_view,gf);` This line seems to return the parent view instead of the one inside. Try to call `findViewById` on that view like `View view= li.inflate(R.layout.piece_view,gf); Piece p=(Piece) view.findViewById(R.id.piece_view);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
//get layout inflater
LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//parent view for my custom view
FrameLayout gf =(FrameLayout)fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.game_field);
//inflation attempt
Piece p=(Piece) li.inflate(R.layout.piece_view,gf);
```

try

```
//get layout inflater
LayoutInflater li =(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//parent view for my custom view
FrameLayout gf = (FrameLayout)fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.item);
//inflation attempt
Piece p = li.inflate(R.layout.piece_view, null);
gf.addView(p);
```

EDIT: To see Image in original size add this parameters to `ImageView`:

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

Comment: Thanks!  The issue was with parent parameter.Actualy I don't need my view to have parent view.Didn't know layoutInflater can accept null as a second argument.
Now problem is my ImageView have 0 width/height even after I set non-zero-sized bitmap as content.And after I add it to display list it appears scaled.Is there way to make it apear with original size?

Comment: with scaleType="center"
my bitmap jumps to the center of the screen when it should be in the top left corner.Also in onLayout I can see view size 1106x736 when actual bitmap size: 51x68
Anyway I found way to set size:
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight());
p.setLayoutParams(parms);

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try it in these two ways:

1. If you want your custom view to be added to the Frame Layout then use

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, mFrameLayout, true);

2. If you do not want your custom view to be added to the Frame Layout then use

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, parent, false);

Possible correction in your code:

**View view =li.inflate(R.layout.piece_view,gf);**

Or 
**View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.piece_view,gf);**

Finally return view;

---

According to the error it seems you are wrongly casting Frame Layout to your custom layout here

**//inflation attempt**
Piece p=(Piece) li.inflate(R.layout.piece_view,gf);